# How to assign variable value to jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
var s="attr" var i=$(s) 
// jQuery(elem).attr(attr,eval("elm"+attr));
jQuery(elem).$(s)(attr,eval("elm"+attr));//i tried this.
```

how to assign a value of variable name in the above code(in place of s).Ie:-instead of adding attr(see the commented line for reference), i need to fetch the value from a variable.

Comment: You would be better to ask this question at stackoverflow, as it's for development questions. You'll likely get a better/faster response.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You aren't using jQuery properly to begin with. The $() function should be used to select an element that you want to modify. So if you have an element with an id "element" you would select it with $("#element"). You can then assign variables either to the jQuery object returned, or to the actual element selected using $("#element")[0].

Comment: To be honest, whoever wrote that second line of code needs to be shot in the scrotum.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you're trying to do here, but the `.val()` function in jQuery will probably help you. This is especially useful for `<form>` elements. If you call `val()` with a parameter, it will change the value of the element:

```
$("yourElement").val("15");
```

If you call `val()` without any inputs, it will return the current value of the element:

```
a = $("yourElement").val();
```

Comment: The function is `.val()`, not `.value()`