# how to assign variable value to jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
var s="attr"
var i=$(s)
// jQuery(elem).attr(attr,eval("elm"+attr));
jQuery(elem).$(s)(attr,eval("elm"+attr));//i tried this.
```

how to assign a variable name in the above code(in place of s) so that i need to add an attribute to the element "elem".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assign variable value to jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343013/how-to-assign-variable-value-to-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Your code has several problems:

1. You've left off end-of-line semicolons (lines 1 & 2)
2. Your code is illogical: you seem to be trying to use jQuery to get an attribute, not an element (line 2)
3. Your jQuery code is completely invalid (line 4)

I'm not quite sure exactly what you're trying to do, but here's how you would use jQuery to get an element and then alter that element's attributes using jQuery's [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
var myElement = $('#myElementID'); // Store the element in a variable with jQuery
$(myElement).attr('attr', 'value'); // Set/alter one of the element's attributes
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help you

Without variable

```
alert($('.view-character-navigation li a[href="shows/angelina-ballerina"]').attr("href"));
```

With variable

```
showurl = '/shows/angelina-ballerina';
alert($('.view-character-navigation li a[href="'+showurl+'"]').attr("href"));
```